# Calculating Percentage of values with 0 grouped by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the percentage of teams with 0 as a value for each month. My current table looks similar to this

```
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
date            team             Value
+-------------+---------------+-----------+
01/01/2018        sales             0
02/01/2018        engineering       3
03/01/2018        Sales             3
04/01/2018        executives        0
01/02/2018        sales             3
02/02/2018        engineering       0
03/02/2018        executives        0
04/02/2018        engineering       2
01/03/2018        sales             5
02/03/2018        engineering       0
03/03/2018        executives        3
04/03/2018        Sales             2
```

and I already tried the query `to_char(date,'YYYY')||''|| to_char(date,'Month') as month,team,100*SUM(CASE WHEN Value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(Value). from table` but that doesn't give the desired output.

my desired output should look similar to this

```
+-------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+
month           Sales            engineering           executives      
+-------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------+
01/2018           50%            0%                     50%     
02/2018            0%            50%                    50%     
03/2018            0%            100%                     0%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to keep the month column as a date, so I would use:

```
select date_trunc(month, date) as yyyymm,
       sum(val) filter (where team = 'sales') * 1.0 / sum(val) as sales,
       sum(val) filter (where team = 'engineering') * 1.0 / sum(val) as engineering,
       sum(val) filter (where team = 'executives') * 1.0 / sum(val) as executives
from t
group by yyyymm;
```

If you really want a string, you can use something like `to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')` or whatever format you prefer.  Only one expression is needed.

EDIT:

The above solves the wrong problem!  I thought it was a proportion of values.  But the proportion that are 0:

```
select date_trunc(month, date) as yyyymm,
       avg( (val = 0)::int ) filter (where team = 'sales') as sales,
       avg( (val = 0)::int ) filter (where team = 'engineering') as engineering,
       avg( (val = 0)::int ) filter (where team = 'executives') as executives
from t
group by yyyymm;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to filter specifically where value is equal to 0

Comment: @Mandibajr . . . Trick question :).  I misunderstood the question.  The actual answer is simpler.  The numbers all add up to 100% on each row, so that biased me toward interpreting it as a proportion within the row.